# Navigation occurs twice for every state transition in AngularJS and Ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a `side menu` page defined like this :

```
<body>
  <ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
      <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
         <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
      </ion-nav-bar>
     <ion-nav-view animation="slide-in-right"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
<ion-side-menu side="left">
 <ion-header-bar class="bar-assertive">
<h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
 <ion-content>
<div class="list side-menu-list">
<a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="home" menu-toggle="left">
<i class="icon ion-home"></i>
Home
</a>
<a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="help" menu-toggle="left">
<i class="icon ion-help-circled"></i>
Help
</a>
<a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="exit" menu-toggle="left" ng-click="exitApp()">
<i class="icon ion-power"></i>
Exit
</a>
</div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
<! -- scripts -->
</body>
```

Now to handle the states I have set up a router like this;

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
    })
   .state('help', {
        url: "/help",
        templateUrl: "templates/help.html",
        controller: "HelpController"
    });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
}
```

And here are my templates files inside `templates folder`

```
<! --home.html  -->

<ion-view title="HOME">
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <h1>I am Home</h1>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Same is `help.html`

Now for the problem part. When I navigate to `home` or `help` using the links from the `side menu` the page body always ends up **sliding twice from left**. The header bar behaves normal. *But the body of the page slides twice and then comes into rest.*

For example when I am in `home.html` and click on **"HELP"** in the **side menu** `then the body of the page 'help' which is "I AM HELP" slides twice from left then comes into rest.`

Basically `event` is not stopping. `Bubbling phase is firing twice`. How can I solve this?

I had similar problem with `JQM` and I used to solve it with `event.stopImmediate.Propogation()`. How do I do it here with `Ionic and AngularJS.`

Or is there any other solution or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue. I am also facing the similar issue  with ui router with subtabs. Calling the controller twice.

Comment: @PraveenVerma I am also having this problem. Did you manage to solve it? (Also, if you're building through phonegap make sure to replace ng-click with hm-tap, otherwise you'll get a 300ms delay and a double click on each click.)

Comment: Hi Robert, I have defined controller twice. one during routing and another at partial page. After removing ng-controller from partial i was getting only single hit.

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by referencing angularjs twice, it will execute the entire framework twice if you do this. Please check if you loaded angularjs multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you inserted in the side menu page with html of `<ion-nav-view animation="slide-in-right"></ion-nav-view>`but remember that index.html has the same within the view portion.

Try removing the slide in your html for the menu page and see if it works.